# Qual è il senso di "pasticciare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Un giorno di fuoco*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Tornammo adagio a sederci sugli scalini di casa, ed io domandai a mio ziastro come potesse esser cosí mortalmente sicuro che quel carabiniere era della Bassa Italia. – Nove su dieci, – mi rispose, – nove su dieci è un napoli. Son tutti di loro nei carabinieri –. Ma la sua voce era come invecchiata, e cosí la sua faccia. Si passò le mani sulle mascelle ed era come se **pasticciasse** nella segatura di ferro.

Ho cercato il verbo "pasticciare" in parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a capire come le diverse accezioni che ho trovato possano avere senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: potreste spiegarmi il significato della frase "era come se pasticciasse nella segatura di ferro" nel brano sopra citato?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da Treccani per [pasticciare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pasticciare/):

> Con sign. affine a *rimestare*, oppure a combinare: *cosa stai
>   pasticciando?* In partic., scrivere, disegnare, comporre o fare altro
>   lavoro, che per sé stesso richiede ordine, precisione, chiarezza (sia
>   sostanziale sia formale o anche soltanto esteriore) in modo
>   disordinato, confuso, poco pulito: *p. un lavoro; ha pasticciato il
>   foglio*, con cancellature, sgorbî e sim.

Il suo ziastro stava massaggiandosi la faccia con un movimento che ricordava quello di quando si rimesta la limatura di ferro senza uno scopo preciso.

I movimenti non erano ordinati o precisi, erano casuali.

Comment: Quindi nel senso di rimescolare le limature di ferro?

Comment: Si, è un’operazione fatta così tanto per fare, senza uno scopo preciso, come scarabocchiare disegnini su un foglio.

Comment: Rimescolare la _segatura di ferro_ passando le mani sulle mascelle sta ad indicare la presenza di una barbaccia ispida, ciò che rafforza il concetto che la sua faccia _era come invecchiata_.